# Syntax of Caml Query in Silverlight 5

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

Is

```
Dim _Query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery
```

a valid query?

Or should it be:

```
Dim _Query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()
```

Or do I have to use:

```
Dim _Query As New CamlQuery()
_Query.ViewXml = "<View><Where><FieldRef Name='FullName'></Where></View>"
```

In which case what should my XML be to return all fields from all list items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `Dim _Query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery` and `Dim _Query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery()` are valid. They are the same query, with a slight difference in syntax. The `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery` returns all list items in a list.

The [Javascript OM description of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407882.aspx) states:

> A query that can be used to recursively get all of the items in a list.

There is an overloaded version of this method in the CSOM to limit your returned values as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.createallitemsquery.aspx

Comment: Np. I remember what my first Silverlight / CSOM project was like...